# Is there a site where I can ask about issues with Nexys 4 DDR (FPGA) boards?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question about programming with specific units (an LED or the 7-segment display) on the [Nexys 4 DDR](https://www.xilinx.com/products/boards-and-kits/1-6olhwl.html) FPGA board. Is there a Stack Exchange site where it may fit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Electronics Stack Exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com) has almost 2,000 questions about [Field-Programmable Gate Arrays](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fpga) right now ... including [yours](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/406674/113522), so it looks like you found the right site already.